# Replace regular expression match with result of applying a function

Tags: python, ruby, regex, python-2.7

I did something like that before in ruby:

```
text.gsub!( SOME REGEX ) do |s|
    s.SOME_STRING_STUFF
end
```

I know there is nothing like rubys "do" in python, but I can't figure out how to do something like that!

Comment: I am not sure what that snippet is doing - but if you want a context wrapper in Python; the [`with statement`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) does that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply pass a function as a replacement to [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
print(re.sub(r't[^t].', lambda m: m.group(0)[::-1], 'testtext')) # settxett
```